# SOAP with .NET 7: Generated different than original

Tags: c#, vb.net, soap, .net-7.0

I am converting a legacy project from .Net Framework 4.6.1 to .Net 7.
The The project uses SOAP services and is a VB project, so the services were added using the add 'Web References' wizard, but with .Net Core+, only C# projects can add 'Connected Services'.
I have added the 'Connected Services' okay using the wizard and the WSDLs for the legacy project but the generated code is different to the original code, namely the method signatures are different, they are even missing parameters or have extra ones and I don't know what these extra parameters are or how to pass in the parameters.

One example is a method `LoadReports` with an extra 'TrustedUsersHeader':

```cs
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<REService.LoadReportResponse> LoadReportAsync(REService.TrustedUserHeader TrustedUserHeader, string Report, string HistoryID)
{
    REService.LoadReportRequest inValue = new REService.LoadReportRequest();
    inValue.TrustedUserHeader = TrustedUserHeader;
    inValue.Report = Report;
    inValue.HistoryID = HistoryID;
    return ((REService.ReportExecutionServiceSoap)(this)).LoadReportAsync(inValue);
}
```

The original generated code does not have this header:

```vb
'''<remarks/>
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("TrustedUserHeaderValue"),  _
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("ExecutionHeaderValue", Direction:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderDirection.Out),  _
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("ServerInfoHeaderValue", Direction:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderDirection.Out),  _
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices/Loa"& _ 
    "dReport", RequestNamespace:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices", ResponseNamespace:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)>  _
Public Function LoadReport(ByVal Report As String, ByVal HistoryID As String) As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("executionInfo")> ExecutionInfo
    Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("LoadReport", New Object() {Report, HistoryID})
    Return CType(results(0),ExecutionInfo)
End Function
```

`SetExecutionParametersAsync` has 2 Header parameters:

```cs
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<REService.SetExecutionParametersResponse> SetExecutionParametersAsync(REService.ExecutionHeader ExecutionHeader, REService.TrustedUserHeader TrustedUserHeader, REService.ParameterValue[] Parameters, string ParameterLanguage)
{
    REService.SetExecutionParametersRequest inValue = new REService.SetExecutionParametersRequest();
    inValue.ExecutionHeader = ExecutionHeader;
    inValue.TrustedUserHeader = TrustedUserHeader;
    inValue.Parameters = Parameters;
    inValue.ParameterLanguage = ParameterLanguage;
    return ((REService.ReportExecutionServiceSoap)(this)).SetExecutionParametersAsync(inValue);
}
```

```vb
'''<remarks/>
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("TrustedUserHeaderValue"),  _
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("ExecutionHeaderValue"),  _
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("ServerInfoHeaderValue", Direction:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderDirection.Out),  _
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices/Set"& _ 
    "ExecutionParameters", RequestNamespace:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices", ResponseNamespace:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)>  _
Public Function SetExecutionParameters(ByVal Parameters() As ParameterValue, ByVal ParameterLanguage As String) As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("executionInfo")> ExecutionInfo
    Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("SetExecutionParameters", New Object() {Parameters, ParameterLanguage})
    Return CType(results(0),ExecutionInfo)
End Function
        
'''<remarks/>
Public Overloads Sub SetExecutionParametersAsync(ByVal Parameters() As ParameterValue, ByVal ParameterLanguage As String)
    Me.SetExecutionParametersAsync(Parameters, ParameterLanguage, Nothing)
End Sub
        
'''<remarks/>
Public Overloads Sub SetExecutionParametersAsync(ByVal Parameters() As ParameterValue, ByVal ParameterLanguage As String, ByVal userState As Object)
    If (Me.SetExecutionParametersOperationCompleted Is Nothing) Then
        Me.SetExecutionParametersOperationCompleted = AddressOf Me.OnSetExecutionParametersOperationCompleted
    End If
    Me.InvokeAsync("SetExecutionParameters", New Object() {Parameters, ParameterLanguage}, Me.SetExecutionParametersOperationCompleted, userState)
End Sub
```

Most baffling of all is the `Render` method:

```cs
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<REService.RenderResponse> RenderAsync(REService.RenderRequest request)
{
    return base.Channel.RenderAsync(request);
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="Render", WrapperNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class RenderRequest
{
        
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices")]
    public REService.ExecutionHeader ExecutionHeader;
        
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices")]
    public REService.TrustedUserHeader TrustedUserHeader;
        
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices", Order=0)]
    public string Format;
        
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices", Order=1)]
    public string DeviceInfo;
        
    public RenderRequest()
    {
    }
        
    public RenderRequest(REService.ExecutionHeader ExecutionHeader, REService.TrustedUserHeader TrustedUserHeader, string Format, string DeviceInfo)
    {
        this.ExecutionHeader = ExecutionHeader;
        this.TrustedUserHeader = TrustedUserHeader;
        this.Format = Format;
        this.DeviceInfo = DeviceInfo;
    }
}
```

Most of the parameters are gone, so how do I pass them in?

```vb
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("TrustedUserHeaderValue"),  _
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("ExecutionHeaderValue"),  _
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("ServerInfoHeaderValue", Direction:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderDirection.Out),  _
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices/Ren"& _ 
    "der", RequestNamespace:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices", ResponseNamespace:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)>  _
Public Function Render(ByVal Format As String, ByVal DeviceInfo As String, ByRef Extension As String, ByRef MimeType As String, ByRef Encoding As String, ByRef Warnings() As Warning, ByRef StreamIds() As String) As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Result", DataType:="base64Binary")> Byte()
    Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("Render", New Object() {Format, DeviceInfo})
    Extension = CType(results(1),String)
    MimeType = CType(results(2),String)
    Encoding = CType(results(3),String)
    Warnings = CType(results(4),Warning())
    StreamIds = CType(results(5),String())
    Return CType(results(0),Byte())
End Function
```

Perhaps I added the WSDL wrong or perhaps I don't understand the headers?
I notice that the generated VB code for 'Render' method uses `ByRef` keyword, so these are 'out' parameters perhaps the headers are like dictionaries and I could get the 'Out' parameters from them?

Does anyone have more experience with SOAP in .Net Core+ who could help me out?

Answer (score 0):

We have about 80 such legacy web services clients that we build to .NET 4.8, 6.0 and 7.0 and publish as (company internal) NuGet packages and the solution that works best for us is to forget about VS automatisms at all and do it - still automatically, but with full control of when and how is what generated - through pre-build steps.

We use a visual studio solution with a project for each service reference (in C# but VB.NET should do just fine). The solution and the service reference projects have 3 build configurations (`Debug`, `Release`, `SvcRef`). When built with `SvcRef`, the service references are regenerated in a pre-build step by a call to `svcutil.exe` with parameter `/targetClientVersion:Version35` (full batch see below).

Where-ever possible we also augment each web client to implement an interface with a method `CheckAccess` (through a partial class in a separate file) that allows us to always ping the same interface method in monitoring tools to check whether the web service is still alive.

Each service reference assembly also provides a factory class that returns a fully configured instance of the client for a given environment (`Test`/`Integration`/`Prod` etc.) to hide all the knowledge needed about the endpoint URLs, communication protocols, authentication and proxy-authentication details needed to correctly consume the webservice (it can happen that `https` is only supported on the production but not on the test environment where a web service must be consumed through simple `http` etc.).

But I got a bit carried away, here the batch similar to what we use in the pre-build step:

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD "$(ProjectDir)"
SETLOCAL

ECHO $(ConfigurationName)
IF /I "$(ConfigurationName)" NEQ "SvcRef" GOTO EOF
IF /I "$(TargetFramework)" NEQ "NET48" GOTO EOF

"..\..\BuildTools\svcutil.exe" "https://server.domain.tld/site/myservice.svc?singleWsdl" /language:VB /out:".\Reference.vb" /namespace:"*,Company.ServiceReference.Product.Service" /serializable /config:.\Sample.config /collectionType:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /targetClientVersion:Version35

:EOF
ENDLOCAL
POPD
```

For the service references re-generation, we point to the according web service of the `Test` environment which includes future interface changes that are not yet live.

For this to work, you need a copy of the `svcutil.exe` in a subfolder of the `<repository-root>\BuildTools` and have the solution in a subfolder of the `<repository-root>` (we use `<repository-root>\Source`).

If the batch should fail, try-out the `svcutil.exe` call outside of Visual Studio with different settings. Some references we have to build with DataContractSerialization and others not, some services support `singleWsdl`, others only `wsdl` in the URL etc.

Additional info for interested C#-programmers: In C# we do also prepend the generated `Reference.cs` file with a `#nullable disable` and a `#pragma warning disable CS1591`.